# Show ticking time using Kendo UI

Tags: kendo-ui

I am wondering if there is any Kendo UI element to display time in a web page, something like the timer show at the bottom right corner of Microsoft Windows, but with seconds shown.

Comment: There is no built in widget for that you have to go with some jquery based plugins .                                                                                                                   http://flipclockjs.com/                                                                 https://www.sitepoint.com/10-cool-jquery-clock-tutorials-analog-digital/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact what @Sean said is true, there's no widget for such task. However, you can use the awesome Kendo UI's method called `toString()` to format time and display it by your own. It is easy, no need jQuery at all:

```
<div id="timer"></div>

var timer = document.getElementById("timer");

window.setInterval(function() {
    timer.innerText = kendo.toString((new Date()), 'HH:mm:ss');
}, 1000);
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/OXIxO)

Check [this doc](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting) for format reference.